# joomla migration 1.5 to 2.5 error undifined

Tags: migration, joomla1.5, joomla2.5

I've try to migrate a website in Joomla from 1.5 to 2.5 using jUpgrade but I've receive the "undefined migrating" error.

Here's the error when I enable the debug:

```
==========
[checks]

1

==========
[cleanup]

1

==========
[decompress]

1

==========
[install_config]

1

==========
[install_db]



==========
[1] [users]



==========
[2] [categories]

.

==========
[3] [content]



==========
[undefined] [undefined]



==========
[undefined] [undefined]



==========
[undefined] [undefined]
```

It seems that it cannot go through the menu migration. I'd tried to empty the menu table but the same error occurs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me the solution was to increase PHP time limit temporarily so you can complete the migration process, it seems that the problem comes if you have much content and jupgrade takes more rows from the content table than your time limit can handle causing a PHP error and that stops the whole process